# Authenticated user can't download audio, even though has permission

Tags: users, files

I have an embedded audio player using HTML5 which is displayed on my guitar lessons site. I have a private file system set up. When I am logged in I can play the audio files fine. If I register as a regular user and go to the same page, it shows the embedded audio player, but no audio plays. This is because drupal is not serving the audio via the media module because for some reason drupal thinks the user is not authorized, even though I specifically set up the roles.

Any ideas how to troubleshoot this?

Thanks!

Comment: do you have any extra modules for permissions, like field permissions? you can check that as well, also please add more details to your question, like what kind of modules you are using for that audio player.

Comment: I just realized that there were additional settings under Config->Media. See my answer, which is still counter intuitive to me.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I didn't realize beyond administering the user roles that I also had to go under Configuration » Media and under private file downloads add a directory '/' under sites/default/files/private... Now it works.